compiling errors for R 4.4.1 on alma linux 9.4
I am compiling R 4.4.1 from source on alma linux 9.4 (docker container)
./configure --prefix ${installdir} \
    --enable-year2038 --with-cairo --with-x --with-libpng --with-jpeglib --with-libtiff \
    --enable-R-shlib --enable-BLAS-shlib --enable-memory-profiling --with-readline \
    --with-blas 

When I run make I get the following error
make[4]: Entering directory '/usr/R-4.4.1/src/library/grDevices'
byte-compiling package 'grDevices'

 *** caught segfault ***
address 0x1802bf1860, cause 'memory not mapped'

Traceback:
 1: solve.default(rgb)
 2: solve(rgb)
 3: drop(whitexyz %*% solve(rgb))
 4: make.rgb(red = c(0.625, 0.34), green = c(0.28, 0.595), blue = c(0.155,     0.07), gamma = 1.8, white = "D65", name = "Apple RGB")
 5: eval(exprs[i], envir)
 6: eval(exprs[i], envir)
 7: sys.source(codeFile, env, keep.source = keep.source, keep.parse.data = keep.parse.data)
 8: doTryCatch(return(expr), name, parentenv, handler)
 9: tryCatchOne(expr, names, parentenv, handlers[[1L]])
10: tryCatchList(expr, classes, parentenv, handlers)
11: tryCatch(expr, error = function(e) {    call <- conditionCall(e)    if (!is.null(call)) {        if (identical(call[[1L]], quote(doTryCatch)))             call <- sys.call(-4L)        dcall <- deparse(call, nlines = 1L)        prefix <- paste("Error in", dcall, ": ")        LONG <- 75L        sm <- strsplit(conditionMessage(e), "\n")[[1L]]        w <- 14L + nchar(dcall, type = "w") + nchar(sm[1L], type = "w")        if (is.na(w))             w <- 14L + nchar(dcall, type = "b") + nchar(sm[1L],                 type = "b")        if (w > LONG)             prefix <- paste0(prefix, "\n  ")    }    else prefix <- "Error : "    msg <- paste0(prefix, conditionMessage(e), "\n")    .Internal(seterrmessage(msg[1L]))    if (!silent && isTRUE(getOption("show.error.messages"))) {        cat(msg, file = outFile)        .Internal(printDeferredWarnings())    }    invisible(structure(msg, class = "try-error", condition = e))})
12: try(sys.source(codeFile, env, keep.source = keep.source, keep.parse.data = keep.parse.data))
13: loadNamespace(package = package, lib.loc = lib.loc, keep.source = keep.source,     keep.parse.data = keep.parse.data, partial = TRUE)
14: withCallingHandlers(expr, packageStartupMessage = function(c) tryInvokeRestart("muffleMessage"))
15: suppressPackageStartupMessages(loadNamespace(package = package,     lib.loc = lib.loc, keep.source = keep.source, keep.parse.data = keep.parse.data,     partial = TRUE))
16: code2LazyLoadDB(package, lib.loc = lib.loc, keep.source = keep.source,     keep.parse.data = keep.parse.data, compress = compress, set.install.dir = set.install.dir)
17: tools:::makeLazyLoading("grDevices")
An irrecoverable exception occurred. R is aborting now ...
make[4]: *** [../../../share/make/lazycomp.mk:9: ../../../library/grDevices/R/grDevices.rdb] Error 139
make[4]: Leaving directory '/usr/R-4.4.1/src/library/grDevices'
make[3]: *** [Makefile:28: all] Error 2
make[3]: Leaving directory '/usr/R-4.4.1/src/library/grDevices'
make[2]: *** [Makefile:39: R] Error 1
make[2]: Leaving directory '/usr/R-4.4.1/src/library'
make[1]: *** [Makefile:28: R] Error 1
make[1]: Leaving directory '/usr/R-4.4.1/src'
make: *** [Makefile:62: R] Error 1

I think this could be linked to the gcc-c++ version (11.4.1). However at the end of the ./configure I get:
  Default C++ compiler:        /usr/bin/g++ -std=gnu++17  -g -O2
  C++11 compiler:              /usr/bin/g++ -std=gnu++11  -g -O2
  C++14 compiler:              /usr/bin/g++ -std=gnu++14  -g -O2
  C++17 compiler:              /usr/bin/g++ -std=gnu++17  -g -O2
  C++20 compiler:              /usr/bin/g++ -std=gnu++20  -g -O2
  C++23 compiler:              /usr/bin/g++ -std=gnu++23  -g -O2

and they seem ok with the instructions on the R webpage.
I could not find details about this error.

You can use your EDIT as an answer to your own question, this way the question can be closed.

I managed to compile using different options and exporting $CXX variable
export CXX=/usr/bin/g++ 
./configure CFLAGS='-g -O0' CXXFLAGS='-g -O0' \
    --prefix ${installdir} \     
    --enable-year2038 --with-cairo --with-x --with-libpng --with-jpeglib --with-libtiff \     
    --enable-R-shlib --enable-BLAS-shlib --enable-memory-profiling --with-readline \     
    --with-blas

